# Unable to partition and install filesystem on san-connected mutipath volume

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition, multipath-storage

Title pretty much says it all. Using Ubuntu 22.04. I have a simple install going -> physical HPE DL360 G9 with two 2-port HBAs connected to an iSCSI switch, which in turn connects to our Nimble storage array. Below is what I've done:

- Installed Ubuntu 22.04 and updated it
- Changed the iSCSI initiator name in the initiator config file
- Changed my NIC names to be understandable (en01 = mgmt0; ens1fs0 = iscsi-1; ens2fs1 = iscsi-2) and applied the changes
- I installed a Nimble Linux toolkit which modifies iscsid.conf and adds multipath.conf "devices" section for Nimble devices
- I then created two iface's with my 2 iscsi NICs and restarted both iscsid and multipathd services
- I configured a Volume on my array and assigned access to it via the iqn of my server
- I then performed a iSCSI discovery via iscsiadm, then did a login.

At this point...all is looking good

- I retrieved the wwid of the Volume connected so I can add a friendly name for it in the multipath.conf file. Still..all good here
- At this point, I reboot the server to refresh everything and make sure my iSCSI target connection automatically reconnects, and it does. Still good
- Here is now my issue. I run fdisk /dev/nimblestorage/ (this is I believe a symbolic link to the connected Volume) and go through the process to partition the disk. Simple process. But, at the end of it after I "write" changes to disk, I receive the following error or warning:

```
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table. Re-reading the partition table failed: Invalid Argument.
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or partx(8)
```

So, I do what the message says to do and reboot. I then attempt to put a filesystem on my partition/volume using the below command:

```bash
sudo mkfs.xfs -b siz=4k -m reflink=1,crc=1 -L test01 /dev/nimblestorage/<vol-name>
```

and receive the following error:

```
mkfs.xfs: cannot open /dev/mapper/<vol-name>: Device or resource busy
```

If I try this via /dev/mapper/, I think it works, but the storage doesn't show when running df -hT

I can't do anything. I've been Internet searching all over the place and nothing I've attempted has worked. What am I missing? Is the issue multipathing? Did I not configure something? Really appreciate any help you all can provide. Even if I don't install the Nimble toolkit and just go by /dev/mapper/... , I get the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had to pick my ‘storage implementation on Linux steps’ apart and piece by piece to see what step(s) the issue laid. I was able to get it all to work fantastic when using only 1 adapter. So the issue obviously had something to do with the multipathing layer, or at least with how multipathing works in Linux. Still learning this!

Nimble has a “toolkit” installer for Linux which includes their “network connection manager” tool to assist with multipathing. In their documentation to partition/filesystem connected devices, they state to use the device: /dev/nimblestorage/ , which is basically a symbolic link of sorts similar to /dev/mapper/, which then points to a dm-# device. Though fdisk displays an annoying warning message after writing a partition to a device, which doesn’t occur when using a local disk or connecting to a san-based LUN using 1 adapter, I think the partition still gets created fine. Why the fdisk warning/error occurs, I still don’t know. For my own anal-ness and sanity, I switched this task to using parted, which also allows me to put a GPT table on the disk as well, so it works out better

To place a filesystem on the device, I can’t use the Nimble-based device name or the “Resource or device is busy” error occurs. And, when I attempted to not use the Nimble name in my testing, but still getting the error, I was using the wrong /dev/mapper/ , thus why I was getting the “Resource or device busy” error for it too. The device was basically a name “higher” up in the device name “tree”...analogous to using /dev/sdb instead of /dev/sdb1. After partitioning the device, the Linux device mapper adds a -part1 at the end of the device name. I wasn’t using that (my tab-completion didn’t add it, so basically somewhat of a typing error on my part). When I did use the /dev/mapper/-part1 device to place a filesystem on the device, it worked fine. I was then able to proceed as normal mounting the device, then using my storage as needed.